# Get all list of month and year from given date to current date

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have variable with datetime as,

```
let givenDateTime = '2021-01-29T04:22:22.148Z';
```

I want to get all months and year in an array from givenDateTime to currentDate.

**Expected O/P : ["April 2021", "March 2021", "February 2021", "January 2021"]**

For this I tried as:

```
let createdDate = new Date(givenDateTime);
let currentDate = new Date();
let dateAndYearList = [createdDate.toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' })];

while (createdDate.setMonth(createdDate.getMonth() + 1) < currentDate) {
    dateAndYearList.unshift(createdDate.toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' 
    }));
}
```

But on console.log(dateAndYearList) , it gives , ** ["April 2021", "March 2021","January 2021"]**, all month from January except for February.

Can anybody tell me how can I get all the months from created month i.e. January to current month i.e. April? If any one needs any further information please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the day of `createdDate` to 1

```js
let givenDateTime = '2021-01-29T04:22:22.148Z';

let createdDate = new Date(givenDateTime);
createdDate.setDate(1);
let currentDate = new Date();
let dateAndYearList = [createdDate.toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' })];

while (createdDate.setMonth(createdDate.getMonth() + 1) < currentDate) {
    dateAndYearList.unshift(createdDate.toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' 
    }));
}

console.log(dateAndYearList)
```